# allow "unsafe" websites to get GeoLocation on smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geocoding

In a form on a website that im building for a school work, i need to check the geolocation of the computer/smartphone when a button its clicked, im using the IIS, so on my computer i just type localhost/form.html to use it, and it works. But on my smartphone, i type the IP of my computer/form.html (when in the same network) i click the button but nothing happens because the google chrome doesnt allow unsafe websites to get the geolocation.

(the code that im using, doesnt really matter because the problem isnt there..)

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    button.addEventListener("click", getLocation);
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Anyone knows how can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "unsafe", you mean non-https websites, correct? The solution is to enable SSL for your website, aka enable HTTPS.

Comment: i just put https:// myIP/form.html, and got a warning, but i clicked continue and it worked, thanks :)